# Presto: Difference in hours between two timestamps?

Tags: sql, datetime, presto

The below gives me results like `1 00:00:00.000` However, I'd like the number of hours elapsed as a float or double.

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ds2) - FROM_UNIXTIME(ds1)
```

Does something like the below exist?

```sql
SELECT HOURS(FROM_UNIXTIME(ds2) - FROM_UNIXTIME(ds1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for [`date_diff`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_diff):

```sql
select date_diff('hour', now(), now() + interval '1' hour)
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1 |